# Delete files via Drive API failed with error: Insufficient permissions for this file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

**Intro:**
Alice prepared an app script that is bound to a Google Sheet. The script generates a Google Doc from the Google Sheet. The doc is stored on Alice's Google Drive. If Alice generates a new Google Doc, then the old one is deleted. The following code is used for that.

```
function delteFile(myFileName) {
  var allFiles, idToDLET, myFolder, rtrnFromDLET, thisFile;

  myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder_id_is_here");

  allFiles = myFolder.getFilesByName(myFileName);

  while (allFiles.hasNext()) {
    thisFile = allFiles.next();
    idToDLET = thisFile.getId();
    rtrnFromDLET = Drive.Files.remove(idToDLET); // API call to drive.files.delete failed with error: Insufficient permissions for this file
  };
};
```

Alice shared the project on Google Cloud Platform with Bob.

1. If Alice generates a Google Doc, then Bob can not successfully execute the above code. The code shows

   > API call to drive.files.delete failed with error: Insufficient permissions for this file

Alice can successfully execute the above code in this case.

2. If Bob generates a Google Doc, then Alice can not successfully execute the above code. The code shows the same error. Bob can successfully execute the above code in this case.

**Question:** 
The project is shared on Google Cloud Platform. What else does Alice need to share?

Comment: Upon the creation of the file, is it being shared with both alice and bob? (by making them editors)?

Comment: Can't delete what you don't own. Use a service account or Team Drive instead of Google Drive

Answer (score 0):

The proper tool for this problem is Google Shared Drive. But if that doesn't work in your situation, you can make your own trash folder (e.g. 'ToTrash'). Then give to the people that can trash, permission to this folder. Instead of trashing you let people use a script (see below) that moves files to your own 'ToTrash' folder. Once in a while you delete all files in the 'ToTrash' folder. For that you can also write a script (not provided but easy to write) that is automatically triggered for example once every day.

```
// TRASHFOLDERID is the Id of your own created trash folder.
// 'file' is a file object you constructed
// by getting it by id, name, or FileIterator

const trashFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TRASHFOLDERID);
file.moveTo(trashFolder);
```

Comment: This is a potentially very confusing solution, since Google Drive already has a trash folder. You shouldn't need to move files to fake trash folders just to work around a poor permission implementation. Google needs to do better. Not being able to delete files on a shared file store is a massive bug.

Comment: Yes. It is indeed a work around and it would be better if Google would handle it with a good permission implementation.