# How can i remove the old converted file and replace with a new file using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to replace the old converted files with the new file. This is because every time i run the script it keeps on duplicating and multiplying in the same folder.

Here is the code:

```
function ConvertFiles() {

var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var r= 2;
for(r= 2;r < sheet.getLastRow(); r++){

var fileId= sheet.getRange(r,1).getValues();
var folderID = sheet.getRange(r,8).getValues();
Logger.log(fileId); 

var files = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var name = files.getName().split('.')[0]; 
var blob = files.getBlob();


var destinationFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);   
Logger.log(folderID); 

var newFile = {
    title : name + '_converted', parents: [{id: 
destinationFolderId.getId()}]}; 
Logger.log(newFile); 

 }
}
```

**My goal is:**

1. To **replace/update** the old converted file into the latest one everytime the script runs **(if it has the same filename)**
2. I would like to **push back the converted `fileId`** into the google sheet to be displayed.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: fileId is undefined in my function perhaps it a global

Comment: As you code is currently it's not reproducible.  Can't get the same errors you are getting

Comment: Can you post an image of Sheet1.  Note: I do not follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for replying cooper. Anyway i have already solved this problem few minutes ago. However, I am having another problem, if you don't mind can i change/edit this question into my current problem?

Comment: @Cooper I have edit my question above based on my current issue. If you don't mind please have a look on it

Comment: Where is the code where you duplicate the file? Kindly include so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Perhaps you should read about a [mcve] because the your code still has unreconciled issues like `fileId` is undefined.  So it I can't reproduce the problem it's rather hard to debug.

Comment: @NaziA there is no specific part of the code where it duplicates the file. The above code is about getting the `fileId` and `folderId` from a google sheet and then convert all the excel file based on the `fileId` and save them into their specific folder destination ( `folderId` ).

What i mean by "duplicating files" here is, whenever i run the above script **multiple times** it will keep on adding the new converted files continuously without replacing the existing one.

Comment: Hi @VishnuKumaran, you either need to update the existing converted file, or recreate it after removing the existing converted file. My script in the answer below does the latter procedure. Have you checked it? I assume your code only inserts file without any checking if the said file is existing or not. Note that `name` in drive isn't the identifier of the files. Multiple files can have the same name but they differ in ID and if you want to have no duplicates with the `name`, you need to check first that `name` is existing before inserting, if they are, remove it first. Check my answer below.

Comment: Hi @NaziA, so i have tried using your code that you have shared with me, when i use it I am getting an error message **"GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: File not found: "**.So this error is referring to line `var newFileID = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, blob, {convert: true}).id;`. So i guess the mistake might be because of it cant move/loop/insert from folder id to another folder id. According to your sample, you are converting the files from same folder id/directory.But in my case i have a few folders. Sorry if im wrong. How can i solve this error

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet you are working on so I can test your issue on my end. @VishnuKumaran

Comment: @NaziA can i know how can i share my sample sheet...how to share in here(comment)?

Comment: make sure your sheet is public, and then share the link in here. @VishnuKumaran. Don't include any confidential details on it.

Comment: @NaziA i have shared the sample sheet as an answer below. hope that will help you

Comment: @VishnuKumaran, I have updated my answer. See edit for the changes or copy the whole script. Nothing really changes but I just used the folderID directly. I've tested this on separate folder for original files and different folders for each converted file. Works as expected. I'm not entirely sure why it fails on your part though. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @NaziA I have tried your code in different sample sheet and it worked. It doesnt work on my current folders over here because its from shared drive. I heard that we cannot delete files that we dont own [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150681/delete-files-via-drive-api-failed-with-error-insufficient-permissions-for-this]. @NaziA do you know how we can implement `setTrashed` method into the code above? I would like to know how we can use it for the replacement of same filename.

Comment: @NaziA The folder that im working on is from **a shared drive** which im using to extract data. Hope you can help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239123/discussion-between-nazia-and-vishnu-kumaran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added comments to show each part of the code. Kindly check the whole script below:

#### Script:

```
function ConvertFiles() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var r= 2;
  for(r= 2;r < sheet.getLastRow(); r++){
    // Use getValue instead of getValues
    var fileId = sheet.getRange(r,1).getValue();
    var folderID = sheet.getRange(r,8).getValue();
    
    var files = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    var name = files.getName().split('.')[0]; 
    var blob = files.getBlob();
      
    var newFile = {
    // Remove '_converted' from name if existing to avoid duplication of the string before adding '_converted'
    // This will allow to have newly converted file "replace" the old converted file properly
      title: name.replace('_converted','') + '_converted', 
      parents: [{
        id: folderID
      }]
    }; 

    var destinationFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); 
    var existingFiles = destinationFolderId.getFilesByName(newFile.title);

    // GOAL #1: To replace/update the old converted file into the latest one everytime the script runs (if it has the same filename)
    // Find the file with same name of the file to be converted
    while(existingFiles.hasNext()) {
      // ID of the file with same converted name
      var oldConvertedFileWithSameNameID = existingFiles.next().getId();

      // Delete before writing
      Drive.Files.remove(oldConvertedFileWithSameNameID);
    }

    // Create new converted file then get ID
    var newFileID = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, blob, {
      convert: true
    }).id;

    // Goal #2: I would like to push back the converted fileId into the google sheet to be displayed.
    // Add the ID of the converted file
    sheet.getRange(r,9).setValue(newFileID);
  }
}
```

#### Sample sheet:

[image: sample sheet]

#### Sample files:

[image: sample files]

#### First run (files):

[image: first run files]

#### First run (sheet):

[image: first run sheet]

#### Updated original files:

[image: updated file]

#### Run after updating original file (files):

[image: update run]

#### Run after updating original file (sheet):

[image: update file]

#### Note:

- This will retain the original file, but will replace the existing converted file of it everytime the script is run.
- I have used `Drive` services.